# When trying to login if already logged in, form just shakes - error message remains empty

Tags: login

I am already logged in (with role administrator). If I try to login again with wp-login.php the form just shakes - the error message above the form remains empty. Following a suggestion on this forum I added the following code to my theme's function.php - it works:
    /* Create error message for new login attempt if user is already logged in */

```
add_filter('login_errors','login_error_message');
function login_error_message($error){
    //create error message for already logged in
    $error = "You are already logged in";
    return $error;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I posted too soon! This always causes the same message to be shown - even when there is another problem such as wrong name or password. I tried modifying the code as follows, but that doesn't help! Does anyone know how to solve this problem?           add_filter('login_errors','login_error_message');

    function login_error_message($error){  
    if (empty($error)) {
        $error = "You are already logged in";
    }
    return $error;
}

Comment: Please add editions via an [edit] directly in your post. Code in comments are unreadable and everybody just ignores it. Comments in general are ignored by many.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working around the error message I would suggest checking if user is already logged in on wp-login.php load. If user is logged in - redirect him/her to wp-admin. You can even add another check and, for example, redirect only administrators to wp-admin, redirect subscribers to site homepage etc.

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'wpse_redirect_login', 1 );
function wpse_redirect_login() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( admin_url() );
    }
}
```

Honestly, that's one of the issues I keep wondering why it isn't in Core.

Comment: 'login_head' is too late to perform a redirect as output would already have started.

Comment: Yes, my bad. It's possible to perform a late redirect with output buffering, however, it requires some extra code which I haven't provided.

Answer (score 0):

`login_errors` filter, which allows us to modify the error message displayed on the login page.

Inside the `login_error_message` function, we check if the user is already logged in using the `is_user_logged_in()` function

```
// Add this code to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin
add_filter('login_errors', 'login_error_message');

function login_error_message($error) {
    // Check if the user is already logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Set custom error message for already logged in users
        $error = __('You are already logged in.', 'text-domain');
    }
    return $error;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can detect whether the current user is logged in and redirect them to their profile page with the following…

```
add_action('wp_loaded','wp_login_redirect_logged_in_user',0);
public static function wp_login_redirect_logged_in_user(){
    global $pagenow;
    if ( in_array($pagenow, array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php') ) ) {
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $profile_page = get_edit_user_link( get_current_user_id() );
            wp_safe_redirect( $profile_page );
            die();
        }
    }
}
```